# static singleton class becoming null

Tags: java, android, android-activity, singleton

I read a lot but couldn't understand how to restore state when some data kept on singletone class. for example

```
public class UserDataKeeper {


    private static UserDataKeeper instance;

    private User mUser;

    private UserDataKeeper(){
    }

    public static UserDataKeeper getInstance() {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new UserDataKeeper();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return mUser;
    }

    public void setUser(User mUser) {
        this.mUser = mUser;
    }
}
```

When my android application come from background user data becoming null. what should I do here for not getting null result.

Is the only solution is save data using SQLite,Preference or something else ?

Comment: user by default will be initialized to null, so are you suing setter for user?

Comment: Note that your implementation is not thread safe

Comment: And, please also note - Singleton is an [Anti-Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern), it might be looking sexy and has a design pattern name - but it's more trouble than benefit usually

Comment: If all you want to do is save a user's details then make your `User` class either `Parcelable` or `Serializible` and save to `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: @amit : Sometimes in Android, Singletons are the best way to go (as long as you know how to use them of course). This is because of the ephemeral nature of many of an Android app's components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you're implementing a Singleton (which is almost always a bad solution), you're still storing the data in memory. After your application is closed the data will be lost. If you want persistent storage then yes, you'll need to have either a SQLite database, or write your information to disk.